# Select a list of user who do not have same lastname

Tags: mysql, sql, select

There is table user with fields id,  firstname, lastname

How to select a list of user who do not have same lastname.

What I mean

```
1 John Dow 
2 James Smith 
3 Jack Daniels 
4 Bill Dow
```

The result of query should be

```
2 James Smith
3 Jack Daniels
```

I have just one solution

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name
  FROM user
  GROUP BY lastname
  HAVING count(lastname) < 2;
```

Need another variant without subquery

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution doesn't have a `subquery`

Comment: how you know that they are family? Just by last name? How if they are have same last name? I can't even seen any relation from that 2 result, how you know they have family?

Comment: Sorry, change question little more. So the result should not content same lastname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned to

> select a list of user who do not have same lastname

Then change your last clause to `HAVING count(lastname) = 1;`

[`See Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21ba87f/5)

Comment: Also you previous variant work fine too.

select a.* from user a
  left join user b on(a.lastname = b.lastname)
  where b.id is null

Need different variants.